# Passing a initial time to CountDownTimer in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, countdowntimer

I have 3 different duration to pass to countDownTimer. User will select 20 seconds, 40 seconds, 60 seconds and with the initial time (initTime), the countdown begins. Somehow it only works if I set the actual value in millisInFuture, and not pass an initial time value.

```
 //private var countDownTimer = object: CountDownTimer( 5000*10, 100) {
   
    private var countDownTimer = object: CountDownTimer(initTime*1000, 100) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "countDowntimer initTime = $initTime", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            timeLeft = millisUntilFinished
            
            timeResult =
                "${(millisUntilFinished / 1000 % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')}:" +
                        "${(millisUntilFinished / 100 % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')} "
            tvNumPairs.text = "$timeResult"
```

I assigned initTime in MainActivity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
        private const val CREATE_REQUEST_CODE = 248
        private const val GAME_REQUEST_CODE = 173
    }

    //private var adapter: MemoryBoardAdapter
    private lateinit var clRoot: CoordinatorLayout
    private lateinit var rvBoard: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var tvNumMoves: TextView
    private lateinit var tvNumPairs: TextView

    /* COUNT DOWN TIMER */
    private var initTime : Long = 0
```

The value in initTime changes based on user selection:

```
 @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun setupBoard() {
        supportActionBar?.title = gameName ?: getString(R.string.app_name)
        supportActionBar?.subtitle = "Memory Game"

        when (boardSize){
            BoardSize.EASY -> {
                tvNumMoves.text = getString(R.string.Easy4x2)
                //tvNumPairs.text = getString(R.string.tvNumPairs_Pairs0_4)
                tvNumPairs.text = boardSize.getTime().toString() + ":00"
                initTime = boardSize.getTime().toLong()
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Easy > initTime $initTime", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            BoardSize.MEDIUM -> {
                tvNumMoves.text = getString(R.string.Medium6x3)
                //tvNumPairs.text = getString(R.string.tvNumPairs_Pairs0_9)
                tvNumPairs.text = boardSize.getTime().toString() + ":00"
                initTime = boardSize.getTime().toLong()

                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Medium > initTime $initTime", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            BoardSize.HARD -> {
                tvNumMoves.text = getString(R.string.Hard6x4)
                //tvNumPairs.text = getString(R.string.tvNumPairs_Pairs0_12)
                tvNumPairs.text = boardSize.getTime().toString() + ":00"
                initTime = boardSize.getTime().toLong()
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Hard > initTime $initTime", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean when you use initTime variable it is not working? it must work if you are doing it correct and can you show where are you assigning initTime variable maybe it is not global or there is something wrong.Can you show your variable code where you are assigning your value.Because i think there is nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: Thanks Barney. I assigned initTime in the MainActivity class. Just updated my question.

Comment: Where is `private var countDownTimer` defined?

Comment: hi Joffrey. It is defined on the first line of the code pasted.

Comment: Well, I have seen that. My question is about where that code is in the bigger picture. You are mentioning disconnected pieces of code, but the problem likely lies in how these things are ordered (see my answer for a wild guess)

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Joffery. I solved the null issue in initTime by changing to the following code. Hope it can help others too.

```
private fun startTimer(initTime : Long) {
        Log.i(TAG, "startTimer()>initTime = $initTime")
        countTimer = object: CountDownTimer(initTime*1000, 100) {
        //countTimer = object: CountDownTimer(50*1000, 100) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "countDowntimer boardsize.gettime = ${boardSize.getTime()}")
                //Toast.makeText(baseContext, "countTimer--initTime = $initTime",
                  //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                timeLeft = millisUntilFinished
                
                timeResult =
                    "${(millisUntilFinished / 1000 % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')}:" +
                            "${(millisUntilFinished / 100 % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')} "
                tvNumPairs.text = "$timeResult"
                //Log.d(TAG, "time Left onTick = $timeLeft boardsize gettime = ${boardSize.getTime()}")    
              
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                

                disableGame = true
                showReplayDialog("Game Over. Play Again?", null, View.OnClickListener {
                    disableGame = false
                    stopTimer()
                    setupBoard()

                })
            }
        }.start()
       
    }
    private fun stopTimer() {
        countTimer.cancel()
        isStarted = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `private var countDownTimer` is the property of a class. If that's the case, it will read the value of `initTime` when that class is instantiated. If it's in your Activity, then you'll get `0` because that's the value of `initTime` at that moment.

You need to create the `CountDownTimer` instance when the value of `initTime` is already set, otherwise you'll get the initial 0.

Comment: Hi Joffrey. Yes, I think that is exactly what's happening. Can u advise me further on where I should create that object? tia

Comment: @EricLow It's hard to tell without the big picture, but you should create it at least when the `initTime` is known/"confirmed". Or when you are about to start it, which is certain to have the most up-to-date `initTime`